# Ipython notebook iptest lib error

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

I am trying to get Ipython notebook running on a new Ubuntu Installation. I have one problem that I can't fixed through googling it. When I run iptest in the console, lib fails. More specifically:

```
~$ iptest lib

Test group: lib
.......................................F..........S......................
======================================================================
FAIL: testIPythonLexer (IPython.lib.tests.test_lexers.TestLexers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/tests/test_lexers.py", line 26, in testIPythonLexer
    self.assertEqual(tokens, list(self.lexer.get_tokens(fragment)))
AssertionError: Lists differ: [(Token.Operator, '!'), (Token... != [(Token.Operator, u'!'), (Toke...

First differing element 3:
(Token.Name.Variable, '$HOME')
(Token.Text, u'$')

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 5:
(Token.Text, u'\n')

- [(Token.Operator, '!'),
+ [(Token.Operator, u'!'),
?                   +

-  (Token.Name.Builtin, 'echo'),
+  (Token.Name.Builtin, u'echo'),
?                       +

-  (Token.Text, ' '),
+  (Token.Text, u' '),
?               +

-  (Token.Name.Variable, '$HOME'),
+  (Token.Text, u'$'),
+  (Token.Text, u'HOME'),
-  (Token.Text, '\n')]
+  (Token.Text, u'\n')]
?               +

    """Fail immediately, with the given message."""
>>  raise self.failureException("Lists differ: [(Token.Operator, '!'), (Token... != [(Token.Operator, u'!'), (Toke...\n\nFirst differing element 3:\n(Token.Name.Variable, '$HOME')\n(Token.Text, u'$')\n\nSecond list contains 1 additional elements.\nFirst extra element 5:\n(Token.Text, u'\\n')\n\n- [(Token.Operator, '!'),\n+ [(Token.Operator, u'!'),\n?                   +\n\n-  (Token.Name.Builtin, 'echo'),\n+  (Token.Name.Builtin, u'echo'),\n?                       +\n\n-  (Token.Text, ' '),\n+  (Token.Text, u' '),\n?               +\n\n-  (Token.Name.Variable, '$HOME'),\n+  (Token.Text, u'$'),\n+  (Token.Text, u'HOME'),\n-  (Token.Text, '\\n')]\n+  (Token.Text, u'\\n')]\n?               +\n")


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 73 tests in 3.282s

FAILED (SKIP=1, failures=1)

______________________________________________________________________
Test suite completed for system with the following information:
IPython version: 4.0.3
IPython commit : 8ff8693 (installation)
IPython package: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython
Python version : 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2]
sys.executable : /usr/bin/python
Platform       : Linux-3.19.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty

Tools and libraries available at test time:
   matplotlib pygments sqlite3

Status: ERROR - 1 out of 1 test groups failed (lib). Took 4.901s.

You may wish to rerun these, with:
  iptest lib

~$
```

Does anyone know what it means and how do i fix it?

thanks,
Karsus